# Link Error C++ Inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have two classes Person and Student. I'm currently trying to derive the Student class from the Person Class.

However, I keep getting a link error.

The error:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `Person::Person()'
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 

class Person { 

  string Name ;

public: 
  Person(void);

  void set(){ 

       cout << "Name:" << endl ;
       cin >> Name ; 
       } 

  string get_Name(){ 
      return Name ; 
      } 


};

class Student:Person { 
  int x, Lab1, Lab2, Lab3, Lab4, Lab5, Lab6, LabPoints, Midterm, Final ;
  float LabAvg, ExamAvg, Prcnt ; 
  string StuName ;

public: 
  Student(void);

  void set(int i){ 
       x = i; 

       cout << "Student " << x << endl << endl ;
       cout << "Name:" << endl ;
       cin >> StuName ;
       cout << "Lab 1 score (1-10): " << endl ;
       cin >> Lab1 ;
       cout << "Lab 2 score (1-10): " << endl ;
       cin >> Lab2 ;
       cout << "Lab 3 score (1-10): " << endl ;
       cin >> Lab3 ;
       cout << "Lab 4 score (1-10): " << endl ;
       cin >> Lab4 ;
       cout << "Lab 5 score (1-10): " << endl ;
       cin >> Lab5 ;
       cout << "Lab 6 score (1-10): " << endl ;
       cin >> Lab6 ;
       cout << "Midterm score (1-100): " << endl ;
       cin >> Midterm ;
       cout << "Final score (1-100): " << endl ;
       cin >> Final ;

       LabAvg = (Lab1 + Lab2) / 2.0 ;
       LabPoints = (Lab1 + Lab2) ; 
       ExamAvg = (Midterm + Final) / 2.0 ;
       Prcnt = (( ( LabPoints / 60.0 ) * 0.6 ) + ( ( Midterm / 100.0 ) * 0.2) + 
       ( ( Final / 100.0 ) * 0.2)) * 100 ;

       } 

  string get_StuName(){ 
      return StuName ; 
      } 

  int get_Lab1(){ 
      return Lab1 ; 
      } 

  int get_Lab2(){ 
      return Lab2 ; 
      } 

  int get_Lab3(){ 
      return Lab3 ; 
      } 

  int get_Lab4(){ 
      return Lab4 ; 
      } 

  int get_Lab5(){ 
      return Lab5 ; 
      } 

  int get_Lab6(){ 
      return Lab6 ; 
      } 

  float get_LabAvg(){ 
      return LabAvg ; 
      } 

  int get_LabPoints(){
      return LabPoints ; 
      } 

  float get_ExamAvg(){
      return ExamAvg ;
      } 

  float get_Prcnt(){
      return Prcnt ; 
      }
};

Student::Student(void){
  x = 0, Lab1 = 0, Lab2 = 0, Lab3 = 0, Lab4 = 0, Lab5 = 0, Lab6 = 0, 
  LabPoints = 0, Midterm = 0, Final = 0 ; 
  LabAvg = 0.0, ExamAvg = 0.0, Prcnt = 0.0 ; 
  StuName = "" ;
}

int main(){ 
  int MaxNumStu = 10, NumOfRep , i ; 
  float FPrcnt ; 
  string LetGrd ; 

  cout << "Number of Students:" << endl ;
  cin >> NumOfRep ; 
  cout << endl << endl ;

  Student obs[MaxNumStu] ; 

  NumOfRep = ++NumOfRep ;
  for(i=1 ; i < NumOfRep ; i++) 
    obs[i].set(i) ; 

  cout << endl << "---------------------------------" << endl << endl ; 

  for(i=1; i < NumOfRep; i++){
    cout << obs[i].get_StuName() << endl << endl; 
    cout << "Lab 1 Score: " << obs[i].get_Lab1() << endl ;
    cout << "Lab 2 Score: " << obs[i].get_Lab2() << endl ;
    cout << "Lab 3 Score: " << obs[i].get_Lab3() << endl ;
    cout << "Lab 4 Score: " << obs[i].get_Lab4() << endl ;
    cout << "Lab 5 Score: " << obs[i].get_Lab5() << endl ;
    cout << "Lab 6 Score: " << obs[i].get_Lab6() << endl ;
    cout << endl << "Average Lab Score: " << setprecision(4) << 
    obs[i].get_LabAvg() << endl ; 
    cout << "Total Lab Points: " << obs[i].get_LabPoints() << endl ;
    cout << endl << "Average Exam Score: " << setprecision(4) << 
    obs[i].get_ExamAvg() << endl ; 

    FPrcnt = obs[i].get_Prcnt() ;

    if ( FPrcnt >= 90 )
         LetGrd = "% A" ;
    if ( FPrcnt >= 80 )
         if ( FPrcnt < 90 )
            LetGrd = "% B" ;
    if ( FPrcnt >= 70 )
         if ( FPrcnt < 80 )
            LetGrd = "% C" ;
    if ( FPrcnt >= 60 )
         if ( FPrcnt < 70 )
            LetGrd = "% D" ;
    if ( FPrcnt < 60 )
         LetGrd = "% F";

    cout << endl << endl << "Overall Grade: " << setprecision(3) << FPrcnt 
    << LetGrd << endl;
    cout << endl << endl ; 
    }
  system( "pause" ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared a default constructor for `Person`:

```
public: 
  Person(void);
```

But never defined it.

In this case, you don't need to have your own default constructor - remove the declaration and let the compiler generate a default for you.
Alternatively, you can define a do-nothing:

```
Person::Person()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `Person::Person(void);` without defining it.

You will be fine if you remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

You declare Person::Person() on line 10, but you never define it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to two fundamental concepts of C++: **constructor of derived class**,**compiler generated member functions**.

For **constructor of derived class**, it is required to call the base class's constructor at first. In this case,

```
Student::Student(void){
   x = 0, Lab1 = 0, Lab2 = 0, Lab3 = 0, Lab4 = 0, Lab5 = 0, Lab6 = 0, 
   LabPoints = 0, Midterm = 0, Final = 0 ; 
   LabAvg = 0.0, ExamAvg = 0.0, Prcnt = 0.0 ; 
  StuName = "" ;
}
```

It does not specify which constructor of class Person to use. So compiler will automatically insert a call of class Person's default constructor, `Person:Person()`.

For compiler generated functions, compiler will generate those following member functions for each class if they are **not** declared

- **Default constructor**
- **Copy constructor**
- **Assignment operator**
- **Destructor**

However, class Person has declared a constructor `Person:Person(void)` so that no default constructor will be generated by compiler. When it comes to link the `Person:Person()` for class Student, the link error is thrown by the compiler.

There are two solutions for the link error.

1. erase the deceleration of `Person::Person(void);`, hence the default constructor will be generated.
2. add the definition of `Person::Person(void);`. The linker will use our own default constructor.

To extend, let us assume the constructor defined in class person is `Person:Person(string name)`.
Then the solution 2 also needs to modify the constructor of class Student.

```
Student::Student(void):Person("any string"){
   x = 0, Lab1 = 0, Lab2 = 0, Lab3 = 0, Lab4 = 0, Lab5 = 0, Lab6 = 0, 
   LabPoints = 0, Midterm = 0, Final = 0 ; 
   LabAvg = 0.0, ExamAvg = 0.0, Prcnt = 0.0 ; 
  StuName = "" ;
}
```